# Shared Listener and Passing in Activity Instance

Tags: java, android

I have an `OnItemClickListener` implementation defined that I use in several Activities and Fragments throughout my application.  I'm currently passing the `Activity` in the constructor, so I can call `startActivity` without getting an error.  I wasn't sure if this is the appropriate approach.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
public class EventSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;

    public EventSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();             
         intent.setClass(mContext, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
         mActivity.startActivity(intent);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application's context and Activity's context are not the same thing. In your code you are supposed to use Activity's context.

Change this:

```
mContext = mActivity.getApplicationContext();
```

To this:

```
mContext = mActivity;
```

**Or**

Alternatively, you dont even need to bother about keeping a separate context object since your **mActivity** is already having reference to context. So, simply use *mActivity* where ever you need to refer to context:

```
public class EventSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public EventSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();             
         intent.setClass(mActivity, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
         mActivity.startActivity(intent);       
    }
}
```